# Python openstacksdk list servers authentication error

Tags: python, openstack, openstack-nova

I've been attempting to use the [openstacksdk library](https://docs.openstack.org/openstacksdk/ussuri/) to query data from my cloud, specifically project instances. However, when I use to list the instances like so:

```
import openstack

conn = openstack.connection.Connection(session=sess)
servers = conn.compute.servers(all_projects=True)
```

I get the following error and it hangs for a while, I'm guessing it's repeatedly trying to authenticate:

```
...
REQ: curl -g -i -X GET https://booboo-booboo.com:443/v2.1 -H "Accept: application/json" -H "User-Agent: test.py keystoneauth1/4.2.1 python-requests/2.24.0 CPython/3.8.5"
RESP: [401] Content-Length: 114 Content-Type: application/json Date: Sat, 05 Sep 2020 00:32:26 GMT Www-Authenticate: Keystone uri='https://booboo-booboo.com:443/v2.0' X-Compute-Request-Id: req-a25d0bd5-6297-4d2b-80b9-4da1d5993c6d
RESP BODY: {"error": {"message": "The request you have made requires authentication.", "code": 401, "title": "Unauthorized"}}
...
```

So instead I used the [nova client API bindings](https://docs.openstack.org/python-novaclient/ussuri/user/python-api.html) to connect:

```
from novaclient import client

conn = client.Client('2', session=sess)
servers = conn.servers.list(detailed=True)
```

and it successfully listed all the instances:

```
...
REQ: curl -g -i -X GET https://booboo-booboo.com:443/v2.1/12ecf4ae6a374ca6b21e58a17fed92c3/servers/detail -H "Accept: application/json" -H "User-Agent: python-novaclient" -H "X-Auth-Token: {SHA256}4c803dc6ba5fb03e5cd69ce7c83cef9167e0570dcaa503baeb245fee7c538981"
RESP: [200] Content-Length: 15 Content-Type: application/json Date: Sat, 05 Sep 2020 00:50:49 GMT Openstack-Api-Version: compute 2.1 Vary: OpenStack-API-Version, X-OpenStack-Nova-API-Version X-Compute-Request-Id: req-401556a9-49e4-4e09-96ce-118536be6b46 X-Openstack-Nova-Api-Version: 2.1
RESP BODY: {"servers": []}
GET call to compute for https://booboo-booboo.com:443/v2.1/12ecf4ae6a374ca6b21e58a17fed92c3/servers/detail used request id req-401556a9-49e4-4e09-96ce-118536be6b46
...
```

I did look at their [openstackclient CLI tool](https://docs.openstack.org/python-openstackclient/ussuri/):

```
openstack server list --all-projects --timing --debug
```

which when run also works and with the debug flag it shows the following outputs:

```
...
compute API version 2.1, cmd group openstack.compute.v2
identity API version 3, cmd group openstack.identity.v3
image API version 2, cmd group openstack.image.v2
network API version 2, cmd group openstack.network.v2
object_store API version 1, cmd group openstack.object_store.v1
volume API version 3, cmd group openstack.volume.v3
neutronclient API version 2, cmd group openstack.neutronclient.v2
command: server list -> openstackclient.compute.v2.server.ListServer (auth=True)
...
```

I'm guessing that it's initializing the multiple different necessary clients for each services. So my question is that is there a way to use the openstacksdk to do the same thing, because I need to query multiple services from OpenStack and I really don't want to keep track of several different clients for the different services.

Following is the code for creating the session object:

```
from keystoneauth1.identity import v3
from keystoneauth1 import session
from keystoneauth1 import loading

def create_loader():
    loader = loading.get_plugin_loader('password')
    auth = loader.load_from_options(
        auth_url=os.environ['OS_AUTH_URL'],
        username=os.environ['OS_USERNAME'],
        password=os.environ['OS_PASSWORD'],
        project_id=os.environ['OS_PROJECT_ID'],
        user_domain_name=os.environ['OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME']
        )
    sess = session.Session(auth=auth)
    return sess
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the problem maybe be located in the specification of the OpenStack parameters (file: clouds.yaml). If you execute this code:

```
import openstack

# Initialize and turn on debug logging
openstack.enable_logging(debug=True)

# Initialize cloud
conn = openstack.connect(cloud='yourcloud')

for server in conn.compute.servers(all_projects=True):
  print(server.to_dict())
```

And the config file should be something like it:

```
clouds:
  yourcloud:
    region_name: <your region name>
    auth:
      username: '<username>'
      password: '<password>'
      project_name: '<project name>'
      auth_url: '<keystone auth. url>'
      domain_name: '<domain name>'
```

If you have no multi region, you can dismiss this parameter (region_name). Domain name usually is requested if you have it defined in your environment.

Giving that, check the configuration data of your keystone url, because it seems that you are calling the version 2 but the openstacksdk gives you the following info:

```
identity API version 3, cmd group openstack.identity.v3
```

Try to use the version 3 in the definition of the auth_url